# SQL - Changing Date_Updated field only if other fields are different?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Example of Query section of SPROC:

```
Update MyTable
SET
  ProductName=@ProductName
 ,ProductPrice=@ProductPrice
 ,Date_Updated=GETDATE()
WHERE ProductID=@ProductID
```

I'd like to use the GETDATE() on the Date_Updated field ONLY IF ProductName OR ProductPrice have changed from their original value before the update was called.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` condition to test if the new value is equal to the previous value of the column.

```
Update  MyTable
SET     ProductName  = @ProductName,
        ProductPrice = @ProductPrice,
        Date_Updated =  CASE WHEN (ProductName <> @ProductName) OR 
                                  (ProductPrice <> @ProductPrice) 
                             THEN GETDATE() 
                             ELSE Date_Updated 
                        END
WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
```

Comment: This seems super close. The problem Im' facing is it only works when updating a pre-existing field. So lets say ProductPrice is empty and I made changes to ProductName - It works great. But if I edit and add a price for the FIRST time, it doesn't update the date field. If I go back in and CHANGE that price, it does update the date field. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: if you mean `ProductPrice` is null, try this additional condition `CASE WHEN (ProductName <> @ProductName) OR 
               (ProductPrice <> @ProductPrice) OR
               (ProductName IS NULL) OR
               (ProductPrice IS NULL)`

Comment: In my quick example I left out a few more fields: ProductDescription, and a couple others... so if I did that wouldn't it update the Date_Updated field every time ProductPrice is null then? Even if other fields don't change? I'm going to try it anyway! BRB! Thanks!

Comment: This turned out how I assumed unfortunately. My second comment in this list still seems to be the problem :( I'll keep plugging away... Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you give sample records that we can play with?

Comment: I'm attempting SQLFiddle for the first time and having some difficulty due to the lack of forms and... well, just, I'm new. Sorry :( Would there be an easy way to check if NULL changes to NOT NULL, then update as well? Perhaps that's a better way to explain it.